# Javascript regex to match atleast one word starting with number across multiple words but with atleast two words

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, html

I am using Javascript Regex.
I have an input field which should pass only the follwing condition

- Value should have only alphabets and numbers
- Value Should have at least two words(can have more than two)
- only One word Should have number(one or more) in the beginning
- Can allow spaces at the end

Please Help on this as I am new to Regex.

I tried with the below code. It worked for two words but it is not allowing more than two words.
`/^[\d]+[a-zA-Z]*\s+[a-zA-Z]+$|^[a-zA-Z]+\s+\b[\d]+[a-zA-Z]*\b$/`

Comment: What are your valid inputs? Show some valid and invalid samples

Comment: it is for street name and Number validation. 
It can be like: 5413 Flat / 3rd Street / 562test test / test 5415 / test 5test
It cannot be : test5 test, te5st test, test te5st, test test55
No special chars allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using positive lookahead you can use this regex:

```
/^^(?=.*\b\d[a-z\d]*\b)(?:\b[a-z\d]+\b[ \t]*){2,}$/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN8hJ0/2)

`(?=.*\b\d[a-z\d]*\b)` is positive lookahead to ensure there is at least one woth that starts with a digit.

Comment: Hi,
This allows single word, and also only numbers are also matched..
That should not be the case
Atleast two words only one with number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex expression .

```
/^[\d]+[a-zA-Z]*\s+[a-zA-Z]+$|^([a-zA-Z]+\s+)*(\b[\d]+[a-zA-Z]*\b)+$/
```